# How do I check that AssertionException is thrown in a Clojure test?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to write a unit test for my `:pre` and `:post` conditions, and my first thought was to do this:

```
(ns myproj.battle-test
  (:use clojure.test
        myproj.battle))

(deftest lose-only-positive-amount-of-health
  (let [actor {:health 100}]
    (is (thrown? AssertionException
          (:health (lose-health actor -5))))))
```

But I can't work out how to reference `AssertionException` from my test file, and get an exception instead:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: AssertionException
```

I've tried various things (and Google hasn't been helpful, presumably because this is far too simple a question) but without any luck, so how do I check that `AssertionException` was thrown?

I realise this is very much a beginner's question; these are my first few lines of Clojure :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exceptions are classes, so just import it.

```
(ns myproj.battle-test
  (:use clojure.test
        myproj.battle)
  (:import a.package.which.contains.AssertionException))
...
```

Locate where (in which package) `AssertionException` is located and substitute it instead of `a.package.which.contains` in the code above.

Or you can use full name instead, just like in `:import` clause above, but this can be tedious if you have more than one places where you use the class.

UPD. I made a mistake. There is no such class, `AssertionException`. There is a class `AssertionError`, and since it is located inside `java.lang` package, it is imported automatically. Clojure pre/post conditions throw it, so just use `AssertionError` instead of `AssertionException`, and your code should run fine.

Comment: Perfect! I am an idiot. Many thanks for pointing out what should have been obvious - I was looking for a problem that wasn't there!